# Flutter - The Method '*' was called on Null

Tags: flutter

Working on a crypto project, I am getting errors in my widget, the cause of the error is the `getBalance method` below

```
 String getBalance() {
    String _unit = getUnit(); // it returns a string 
    return boolFrom
        ? (balances[_unit]).toStringAsFixed(4)
        : ((balances[_unit] * rates[_unit]) ?? 0).toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
```

When I tried calling getBalance onInit State

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('Get Balance is ${getBalance()}');
  }
```

I get the error `NoSuchMethodError: The method '*' was called on null`

Comment: balances[_unit] is probably null.

Comment: Without seeing where/how `balances` is defined, it is hard to say, but I would imagine it's because `balances` is `null` when you're trying to multiply its value. You should either make it not nullable, or check for its null state before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code with below.

```
String getBalance() {
    String _unit = getUnit(); // it returns a string 
    return boolFrom
        ? ((balances[_unit] ?? 0)).toStringAsFixed(4)
        : (((balances[_unit] ?? 0) * (rates[_unit]) ?? 0)).toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that balances[_unit] and rates[_unit] have a not null value.